# json data, get the lowest price, but dont know parent label

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am looking to get the lowest price from some json data, I get the info from an api call, and json_decode it.

The format is:
products
productnumber -> price

$product_array['products'][..changingnumber..]['value']

I dont know the productnumber (and don't need it either). I do want find the lowestprice for all productnumbers combined

```
$price = min($product_array['products'][..changingnumber..]['value']);
```

Is there a way to do this? or is there some documentation that can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First map the 'value'-s, transform them into a simple array containing all the prices:

```php
$all_prices = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['value'];
}, $product_array['products'])
```

Then just choose the minimum:

```php
$price = min($all_prices);
```

Or combined into a single statement:

```php
$price = min(array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['value'];
}, $product_array['products']));
```